# How to extract elements of a list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list with several vectors which looks like this :

```
$`56`
[1] "OTU2998"             "UniRef90_A0A1Z9FS94" "UniRef90_A0A257ESC3"
[4] "UniRef90_A0A293NAV3" "UniRef90_A0A2E1NMU8" "UniRef90_A0A2E1NPX9"
[7] "UniRef90_A0A2E1NQL1" "UniRef90_A0A2E1NRD2" "UniRef90_X0UC66"    

$`57`
[1] "OTU3820"             "UniRef90_A0A1Z9H3N2" "UniRef90_A0A2D5I161"
[4] "UniRef90_A0A2E6PRN5"

$`58`
[1] "OTU4452"                "UniRef90_A0A1Z9KBI8"    "UniRef90_A0A2E1VTI6"   
[4] "UniRef90_A0A2G2KCN6"    "UniRef90_UPI000BFEC744"

$`59`
[1] "OTU0245"             "UniRef90_A0A1Z9MPM9" "UniRef90_A0A2E2ME98"
[4] "UniRef90_A0A2E8X9N7"
```

Is there a way to only extract the "OTUXXX" information? I mean, I would like to get something like this :

```
$`56`
[1] "OTU2998"       

$`57`
[1] "OTU3820"  

$`58`
[1] "OTU4452"   

$`59`
[1] "OTU0245"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the `purrr::map` family of functions for their ease of passing functions and arguments. Two quick options for extracting those elements are with `grep` using `value = T` to return the matching strings, not just their indices, or with `stringr::str_subset` which does the same.

The regex here matches strings that begin with "OTU", followed by 1 or more digits to the end.

Both methods scale for multiple matches at a time: I added an item "OTU1234" in the last list element to illustrate this.

```r
dl <- list(
  `56` = c("OTU2998", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9FS94", "UniRef90_A0A257ESC3", "UniRef90_A0A293NAV3", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NMU8", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NPX9", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NQL1", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NRD2", "UniRef90_X0UC66"),
  `57` = c("OTU3820", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9H3N2", "UniRef90_A0A2D5I161", "UniRef90_A0A2E6PRN5"),
  `58` = c("OTU4452", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9KBI8", "UniRef90_A0A2E1VTI6", "UniRef90_A0A2G2KCN6", "UniRef90_UPI000BFEC744"),
  `59` = c("OTU0245", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9MPM9", "UniRef90_A0A2E2ME98", "UniRef90_A0A2E8X9N7", "OTU1234")
)

purrr::map(dl, ~grep("^OTU\\d+$", ., value = T))
#> $`56`
#> [1] "OTU2998"
#> 
#> $`57`
#> [1] "OTU3820"
#> 
#> $`58`
#> [1] "OTU4452"
#> 
#> $`59`
#> [1] "OTU0245" "OTU1234"
purrr::map(dl, stringr::str_subset, "^OTU\\d+$")
# same output as above
```

Answer (score 6):

We can loop through the `list` and extract the elements that match the substring 'OTU' at the beginning (`^`) of the string followed by four digits (`\\d{4}`) till the end (`$`) of the string with `grepl`

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) x[grepl("^OTU\\d{4}$", x)])
#$`56`
#[1] "OTU2998"

#$`57`
#[1] "OTU3820"

#$`58`
#[1] "OTU4452"

#$`59`
#[1] "OTU0245" "OTU1234"
```

NOTE: Using only `base R` methods

---

Or if we are a tidyverse aficionado, then use `keep`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1, keep, str_detect, '^OTU\\d{4}$')
```

#### data

```
lst1 <-  list(
  `56` = c("OTU2998", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9FS94", "UniRef90_A0A257ESC3", "UniRef90_A0A293NAV3", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NMU8", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NPX9", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NQL1", "UniRef90_A0A2E1NRD2", "UniRef90_X0UC66"),
  `57` = c("OTU3820", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9H3N2", "UniRef90_A0A2D5I161", "UniRef90_A0A2E6PRN5"),
  `58` = c("OTU4452", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9KBI8", "UniRef90_A0A2E1VTI6", "UniRef90_A0A2G2KCN6", "UniRef90_UPI000BFEC744"),
  `59` = c("OTU0245", "UniRef90_A0A1Z9MPM9", "UniRef90_A0A2E2ME98", "UniRef90_A0A2E8X9N7", "OTU1234")
)
```

Comment: Actually, there could be more than one "OTUXXX"  in the vector and they could located randomly in the vectors